# Elastic search batch insert using curl is not working

Tags: bash, curl, elasticsearch, benchmarking

I'm performing a small benchmark on an Elastic Search cluster. My benchmark script is written in bash and uses curl.

I'm writing the data to a file that I'm posting to the REST API:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/benchmark/external/_bulk?pretty' \
     --data @$DATAFILE
```

My `$DATAFILE` is very simple, and has all newlines in place:

```
{"index":{"_id": "1"}}
{"data":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
{"index":{"_id": "2"}}
{"data":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
{"index":{"_id": "3"}}
{"data":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
...
```

But when I try to do my post I keep receiving the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]",
  "status" : 400
}
```

I understand that my input is not validated, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[curl](http://curl.haxx.se) removed the newlines before the data was sent!

The `--data` parameter should be replaced with [`--data-binary`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/benchmark/external/_bulk?pretty' \
     --data-binary @$DATAFILE
```